# Is the c++ mutable keyword bad for threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

From my understanding of the mutable keyword, one of its primary uses is caching data and computing them when needed. Since they can change (even though they are const) wouldnt it be unsafe or pointless to use them? The caching part modifies the data so there would need to be a lock and from my understanding when you write for multithreads the data should NEVER change and copies should be made and returned/chained together.

So is it pointless or bad to use C++'s mutable keyword?

Comment: I would say you actually misunderstand the `mutable` keyword. Where'd you get this idea that it's intended to affect data caching?

Comment: @Jonathan:  Caching of data is a very common use of `mutable` data members.  If you have a const member function that performs some expensive task and you know that the function gets called frequently, one typical optimization is to introduce a mutable data member to cache the results of the expensive task so that future calls to that member function are faster.

Comment: Yes, but that's a use case, not the meaning of the keyword.

Comment: @Jonathan:  The OP didn't say that was the meaning of the keyword; he said it was the primary use of the keyword (it would be better phrased, perhaps, if it said "one of its primary uses is..." instead of "its primary use is...").

Comment: Look, the OP is confused.  The `mutable` keyword is totally orthogonal to threading.  Really, `mutable` has nothing more to do with threading than `const` does.  *Any* modifications to data that is shared between threads, regardless of whether the data is `mutable` or not, must be synchronized.  James McNellis pointed out a possible case where the `mutable` keyword in a threaded program could lead to a false sense of safety, but that barely justifies associating the two concepts because it's not as if the `const` keyword (or anything else in C++03) makes any *guarantees* about thread-safety.

Comment: @Charles Salvia: I clearly said the data would be modified and must be synchronized. Theres no confusion on my part

Comment: @acidzombie24: ... but you implied that `const` is related to multithreading which it is not. It is not safe to call a `const` method in a multithreaded environment without locks if any other thread may be calling a non-`const` method on the same object. From that point of view, `mutable` is as unrelated to multithreading as `const` is. On the other hand, it is considered safe to call methods that do not change the object from multiple threads (provided there is a guarantee that no other thread modifies the object), but that is not the same as saying that calling a `const` method is safe.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Yes exactly. But many would assume when it is const that it wouldnt modify the class (or at least in a non safe manner). Thus my point, is it 'bad' to use the mutable keyword. I would just write the class to not use it in order to get better performance. I'm really just asking if there is a case where it would make sense to use the mutable keyword because in most cases you would avoid the ability to modify data if possible.

Comment: @acidzombie24: When writting multithreaded code, more than with any other type of program, the advice would be make it *right* then make it *fast* only after measuring and if it is required. Not locking might be a solution for some particular problem, but in the general case, chances are that you will mess it up and have a really hard problem trying to debug the code later. Lock-free code requires a lot of attention, and that means actually knowing what each function actually does or does not.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Do you need to lock when calling a method `int foo() const` to obtain a consistent result if there are no mutable attributes in the object? It depends on `foo`, in the best case, the `int` is only read from the object, and it is word aligned and you might pull it up without locking. In the worst case, the actual result is calculated (without modifying anything) from more than one attribute or is not correctly aligned, either of those cases would make the unlocking call unsafe. The problem is not the `mutable` keyword, but *what* the function does and *how*

Comment: As a matter of fact, the standard library doesn't use ever any `mutable` member since the standard guarantees that all `const` function members are thread-safe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So is it pointless or bad to use C++'s mutable keyword?

No; the `mutable` keyword is A Good Thing.  `mutable` can be used to separate the observable state of an object from the internal contents of the object.

With the "cached data" example that you describe (a very common use of `mutable`), it allows the class to perform optimizations "under the covers" that don't actually modify the observable state.

With respect to accessing an object from multiple threads, yes, you have to be careful.  In general, if a class is designed to be accessed from multiple threads and it has `mutable` variables, it should synchronize modification of those variables internally.  Note, however, that the problem is really more a conceptual one.  It's easy to reason that:

1. All of my threads only call const member functions on this shared object
2. Const member functions do not modify the object on which they are called
3. If an object is not modified, I don't need to synchronize access to it
4. Therefore, I don't need to synchronize access to this object

This argument is wrong because (2) is false:  const member functions can indeed modify mutable data members.  The problem is that it's really, really easy to think that this argument is right.

The solution to this problem isn't easy:  effectively, you just have to be extremely careful when writing multithreaded code and be absolutely certain that you understand either how objects being shared between threads are implemented or what concurrency guarantees they give.

Comment: If a class is designed to be accessed from multiple threads and it has *any* non-constant variables, it needs to synchronize modification of those variables.

Comment: @Charles:  Well, I think it can be argued that it's more of a problem with `mutable` data members.  If you have a number of threads with const references to a shared object, it's often reasonable to assume that you can call those const member functions without any synchronization.  It's easy to forget about mutable and incorrectly think that const member functions cannot mutate the underlying state at all.

Comment: @James: One rule I always follow: If your immutable data is just that -- immutable **data** -- then your "object" had better not have any methods, and it had better just have members that are all const and that transitively point to immutable members. If you can satisfy those conditions, then feel free to access the "object" (aka data aggregate) without locks. If your code is calling any *methods* without locks, though, the code is unsafe, whatever the conditions might be.

Comment: @Lambert: I think that's a bit extreme. For example, if you have a C++0x-compliant containers library you are guaranteed that you can iterate over the container concurrently so long as you don't perform any operations that invalidate iterators (there might be more restrictions than that; I'm not 100% certain about all of the concurrency enhancements to the Standard Library, but this is my understanding.  I'd certainly do more research if I wanted to rely on this.) A class can provide explicit gurantees about its concurrent usability.

Comment: @James: Okay, that's a bit extreme, since there's a little exception: "Except when the class *explicitly* guarantees thread safety". But take that with caution -- I *only* use that statement for wrapper objects whose sole purpose is to provide thread safety, because there's pretty much no point in making any other object thread-safe -- multiple methods calls are almost always unsafe, even if the underlying container is safe. (Eg: Add an object, then remove it -- even if each of those is synchronized, they aren't synchronized together, so why lock the container both internally and externally?)

Comment: @James: once again I agree, though I'd be even more precise. Even without mutable, since `const` is not propagated by pointers (unfortunately ?) `const` methods on an object can actually modify its state. Whether it's good or bad is arguable, what is sure is that the language allow it and that it's left to the developer to get it right.

Comment: @Matthieu: Exactly -- that's why I consider "const" to be like a "permission" limitation for the viewer rather than a binding contract for the object. To me, it means "you can't write here" rather than "this data is immutable".

Comment: @Lambert: actually, there are 2 uses. Some users will use `const` as binding (physical constness), while others (like me) prefer it to express logical constness (on the observable state of the object) with the reasoning that unobservable state (like caching) is a detail implementation. To each his own, I guess, but better not mix the two concepts in a code base :)

Comment: @Matthieu: Haha I see what you mean, but I guess my interpretation is choice 3: it's a read-only permission flag; it says nothing about how the object behaves, unless it's POD with no embedded pointers (and hence unless it has no methods).

Comment: By the way, you might find [this link about const versus immutable in D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/const-faq.html) interesting.

Comment: @Lambert: BTW about methods and POD. Some languages have methods on enums. How weird is that? I have however thought that was weird then found a use for it. Anyways i reading that D link now and i think POD and Classes should be considered different things and have a different name. Typically i call structs as POD and classes as things i dont really have an array of ;)

Comment: @acidzombie24: Yeah, enum methods are kind of weird, like in Java (and maybe D, I'm not sure)... I can get over them, though, because I have yet to see one that performs any kind of mutation on anything. And yeah, POD isn't a great term -- in fact, I don't like that in C++, classes are just private structs. In other languages, there's many clear differences (e.g. C#, D), and only structs can be POD, not classes (although obviously not all structs are POD). And I like your last sentence, although I sometimes *do* have arrays of objects. :)

Answer (score 10):

On the opposite end, most of my multithreaded code *requires* the use of the `mutable` keyword:

```
class object {
   type m_data;
   mutable mutex m_mutex;
public:
   void set( type const & value ) {
      scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );
      m_data = value;
   }
   type get() const {
      scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );
      return m_data;
   }
};
```

The fact that the `get` method does not modify the state of the `object` is declared by means of the `const` keyword. But without the `mutable` modifier applied to the declaration of the `mutex` attribute, the code would not be able to lock or release the mutex --both operations clearly *modify* the `mutex`, even if they do not modify the `object`.

You can even make the `data` attribute mutable if it can be lazily evaluated and the cost is high, as long as you do lock the object. This is the *cache* usage that you refer to in the question.

The `mutable` modifier is not a problem with multithreaded code, only when you try to do *lock-less* multithreading. And as with all *lock-less* programming, you must be *very* careful with what you do, regardless of `const` or `mutable`. You can write perfectly unsafe multithreaded code that calls `const` methods on objects with no `mutable` attributes. The simple example would be removing the mutex from the previous code and having N threads perform only `get()`s while another thread performs `set()`s. The fact that `get()` is const is no guarantee that you will not get invalid results if another thread is modifying.

Comment: Wouldnt it be just as safe to not lock get()? The only way i can see m_data being invalid is if m_data happens to be >32 or 64 bits and it has to do several assignments to copy the complete object. Is this the only reason why? if m_data was a pointer then i dont see any reason to lock in get.

Comment: @acidzombie24: It all depends on the architecture you are working with and a bunch of other factors, atomicity of reads/writes is not enforced by the language. If `type` is a struct that contains 4 characters then the read will most probably not be atomic. Even if it is a single 32bit value in a modern intel processor, reads could be non-atomic if the data (in this case `object`) is not word aligned. Again, when writting lock-free code you need to take *many* things into account.

Comment: For your specific example, I will recomend a ReadWrite Lock [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

Comment: @Niki: There's an overhead on read write locks, and it comes with its own set of problems.  If the critical section is small, or the number of readers/reads is not overwhelmingly larger than the number of writes (as in multiple orders of magnitude larger) you may be better off with a plain mutex.

Comment: @David Rodríguez Finally it all depends from the frequency of class usage, what is type, and how long it take for get() to execute. RWLock is always heavier, but can also be implemented in a way to get heavy when on contention while writing. But I am sure you very much know all that. Right tools for the right problem.

Comment: @Niki: in my personal experience, and this is completely biased, I have never encountered a case where RWLock was the better solution. I have had cases where it was better, but after working on reducing the critical section sizes plain mutex ended up being the better solution.

Measure, your mileage may vary. But I have removed a fair amount of RWLocks in the codebase I work with for good reasons. That's my personal experience, RWLocks *sound* great, but they are not *that* great.

Comment: @David Rodríguez Thank you for sharing your experience and to be honest, I almost don't use RWLock in my code either and only for internally built database access where most of time read is needed and was choking too much because of the normal locks. Still, the "right tools for right job" is always to rule to follow, with "simple is beautiful"

Answer (score 2):

No, the mutable keyword is so that you can have fields inside an object that can change even when the object is const, such as for metadata that isn't part of an object's properties but its management (such as counters, etc.). It has nothing to do with threading.

Comment: Threading _is_ a problem here.  If you have a number of threads, all with const references to some shared object, it's easy to assume that all of those threads can call const member functions on that object without any type of synchronization.  However, if there are mutable data members that are modified by those const member functions, you must ensure that those modifications are correctly synchronized.

Comment: What I meant is, the keyword itself has nothing to do with threading, the way one like `volatile` does. And I *never* assume that calling methods on a const object from two threads works -- not because of this, but because of the fact that while `const` only means that the object doesn't change, it doesn't say anything about the targets of any or references it might have -- so you could modify something incorrectly even through const references without mutable data.

Comment: You're wrong about mutable, it allows member vars marked mutable to be modified in methods marked const, regardless if the instance they get called on is const or not.

Comment: Huh? Isn't that exactly what I wrote in my post? ("the mutable keyword is so that you can have fields inside an object that can change even when the object is const...")

Comment: Certainly the problem is a conceptual one:  it's pretty easy to reason that (I) all of my threads only call const member functions on this shared object, (II) const member functions do not modify the object on which they are called, (III) if an object is not modified, I don't need to synchronize access to it, therefore (IIII) I don't need to synchronize access to the object.  This argument is wrong because (II) is false, but it's really, really easy to think that this argument is right.

Comment: @James: You're right that (II) is false, but my point is, it's not even because of this reason. Even if `mutable` didn't exist, and even if the object's fields never change, what they *point* to can change, and hence so it isn't safe to use `const` for multithreading, even if `mutable` didn't even exist.

Comment: (Also, I don't remember if you can have `const` references to mutable objects or not, but I always think of `const` as a `const` *view* of a potentially mutable object, not a constant object, for the reasons above, whether or not `mutable` exists.)

Comment: @Lambert:  Yes, you can have a const reference to a non-const object.  If I understand your comment correctly, you are arguing that it's a more fundamental issue and that when using an object from multiple threads, you really need a good understanding of what concurrency guarantees it makes.  I agree with that, 100%.  I suppose my argument is more along the lines of, "it's potentially easier for a user of the class to screw up if there is hidden, unsynchronized mutable state."

Comment: Example: If you have a `const` file writer, you can't assume it's synchronized simply because every field (OS handle, etc.) is `const`, even if it *never* changes -- simply because you have no idea whether the pointee of the handle is also const. (@James: Edit, about your comment: Yes, it's a much more fundamental issue, and until today, I never even saw the words `mutable` or `const` in the same sentence as *synchronize*... they're completely different and make no guarantees about each other in any way, real or imagined.)

Comment: -1. Not because your wrong (your right, at least in these comments). But i didnt ask if mutable keyword has anything to do with threading. Just if its bad to use them with threading.

Comment: @Lambert: You said "even when the object is const" I said "even when the **method** is const regardless if the **object is const or not** ". Slight distinction, even if the this pointer is const inside a const method.

Comment: Also lets say stl string class uses the mutable keyword when calling c_str(). You would expect II to be true because it isnt something obvious like a const array pointing to (nonconst) members. You think its a const string that never changes.

Comment: +1 because I agree with your reasoning that it's a more fundamental issue.  It's just an unfortunate problem that many people are not extremely careful when writing multithreaded code (of course, I know I've fixed bugs in my own code too where I wasn't as careful as I should have been).

Comment: @acidzombie24: Well, the answer wasn't "yes" or "no" because you seemed to be misunderstanding the point of "mutable". It's simply unrelated to threading, it doesn't affect the good-ness or bad-ness of the code.
@Eugen: I still don't see anything wrong, even subtly. Could you please clarify what's incorrect/incomplete about what I said?
@acidzombie24: The issue is, you never **ever** call a method on an object from two threads at once, whether or not it's a constant, and whather or not `mutable` exists.