# C++ std::map cache using std::string as the key value

Tags: c++, dictionary, caching

I am writing a cache for a game for school. The idea is that this cache stores Meshes, Materials, etc. and uses the location on the drive as a key so they only have to be loaded once and after that can be retrieved from the cache through the same command as they are inserted with. The problem I am running into seems to be that I cannot add items to the cache anywhere except for in the constructor. The relevant code is as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include "mge/materials/AbstractMaterial.hpp"
#include <string>

class Resources
{
public:
    ~Resources();
    static Resources* GetInstance();
    AbstractMaterial* GetMaterial(std::string location) const;
    Mesh* GetMesh(std::string location) const;

private:
    Resources();
    static Resources* _instance;
    std::map<std::string, AbstractMaterial*>    _materialCache;
    std::map<std::string, Mesh*>                _meshCache;
};
```

relevant method for loading meshes (almost identical for Materials):

```
Mesh* Resources::GetMesh(std::string location) const
{
    Mesh* foundMesh = _meshCache.find(location)->second;
    if (foundMesh == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The requested mesh was not stored in the cache yet!" << std::endl;
        foundMesh = Mesh::load(config::MGE_MODEL_PATH + location);
        if (foundMesh == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "The requested mesh was not found on the disk either!" << std::endl;
            return nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            //_meshCache[location] = foundMesh; //not working
            //_meshCache.insert(std::pair<std::string, Mesh* >(location, foundMesh)); //
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The requested mesh was found in the cache!" << std::endl;
    }
    return foundMesh;
}
```

Neither versions of the insertion into the map seem to work, they both give rather strange errors before even compiling:

The first variant (map[key] = value) gives these errors:

```
"no operator "[]" matches these operands"
```

and

```
"binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<std::string,AbstractMaterial *,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
```

And the second variant (map.insert(Key, Value)) gives these errors:

```
"no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=Mesh *, _Pr=std::less<std::string>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, Mesh *>>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)"
```

and

```
"'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert': 6 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer"
```

I do not understand any of these errors since they are rather vague in my opinion, nor does what I do get from them, explain why this code does work in the constructor but not in the GetMaterial and GetMesh methods.

I would like to use this system for easy/fast assset loading, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `GetMesh(std::string location) const`: You cannot modify a member variable in a `const` member function

Comment: Your method GetMesh is marked const. As such, the method has a const this pointer and you cannot modify member variables (this is what const is all about here). Solution: either remove the const or mark your member variables (*Cache) as mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared `GetMesh(std::string location) const`

You cannot modify a member variable in a `const` member function.

However, you're essentially implementing a lazy-loading pattern. From the user's perspective, their object is not changing, so you really *do* want to modify your cache! ([It's logically `const`, but not physically so](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#logical-vs-physical-state))

Declare them as `mutable`:

```
mutable std::map<std::string, AbstractMaterial*>    _materialCache;
mutable std::map<std::string, Mesh*>                _meshCache;
```

EDIT:
If you're accessing your class in a multi-threaded context, you should synchronize a `mutable` variable just like you'd synchronize any non-const variable. [Check out this other StackOverflow discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628801/27678)

Comment: I would add a big scary warning about the consequences this has on thread safety, especially if some unsuspecting teammate ends up using this class as a client.

Comment: @gd1: Fair enough

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `operator[]` on a `const std::map` since it might try to insert a new element. You also can't `insert` into a `const std::map` for obvious reasons. Your method is const so `_meshCache`, a member of `this`, is treated `const`. Perhaps you want to make `_meshCache` [mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)? Beware that using `mutable` has implications regarding concurrency.